# How to return self on jQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have this code in HTML

```
<div class="details-content">
    <p class="biography user_fillable inline_editable" data-id="Biography"></p>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on the paragraph, it will change into a text field. And it is done via plugin.

Plugin code:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.inlineeditor = function (callback) {

        var $txt = $('<input type="text" class="inline-editor-text"/>');

        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this);

            $this.on('click', function () {
                var _txt = $txt.clone().val($this.text()).insertAfter(this);

                $this.hide();
                _txt.select()
                    .on('keydown', function (e) {
                        if (e.which == '13') {
                            $this.text(_txt.val()).show();
                            _txt.remove();
                            if (callback) {
                                callback($this.text());
                            }
                        } else if (e.which == '27') {
                            $this.show();
                            _txt.remove();
                            if (callback) {
                                callback(null);
                            }
                        }
                    }).on('blur', function (e) {
                        $this.show();
                        _txt.remove();
                        if (callback) {
                            callback(null);
                        }
                    });
            });
        });

    };
})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
<script>
    $(function(){

    var $inlineeditable = $('.inline_editable');

        $inlineeditable.inlineeditor(function (data) {
            var $this = $(this), id = $this.data('id');
            if (data != null) {
                alert(data);
                alert(id);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

I can get the data, but not the 'this' object.
I want to get the '`this`' object, which is equivalent to:

```
<p class="biography user_fillable inline_editable" data-id="Biography"></p>
```

I am doing `return this.each(function () {` but it seems not to work.

[Here is the sample](http://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsCode/KCuH5/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly set the `this` context when calling the callback. At the moment, since you're not calling the function as a method of an object, the `this` context defaults to the global `window` object. Thus, `$(this)` in your callback becomes equivalent to `$(window)` - not exactly what you'd need.

You should call the callback using [`Function.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) which accept the `this` context as first parameter, like so:

```
callback.call($this[0], $this.text());
callback.call($this[0], null);
```

Comment: Better just pass `this` (or `$this[0]`, since `this` seems to refer to the `input` field, not the original element, but not `$this`), to be compliant with other jQuery methods.

Comment: @FelixKling Good call! Updated.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens I changed `callback.call(this, $this.text());` to this `callback.call($this, $this.text());`, and I got what I need to return. Is this Okay? Thanks!

Comment: @fiberOptics Ah, I see the problem. The `this` context where you call the callback is actually the `_txt` element. You should use `$this[0]` then which points to the non-wrapped editor element as suggested by @FelixKling.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to interpret your question; I am assuming your problem is not about returning (right now you are returning the jQuery object your plugin has been called on, which is a good prectice as it makes your plugin call chainable), but setting `this` inside the callback passed to your plugin to the DOM element your plugin is processing. That is done by using `callback.call(<value for this>, <first param>, <second param>, ...)` instead of `callback(<first param>, <second param>, ...)`.